# Can only move object origin in object mode, cant move the mesh

Tags: modeling, origin

I can only move the origin point of the mesh that I selected in object mode, but not the whole mesh
Did I set anything up by accident?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have likely enabled the *Transform Affect Only* option for *Origins* by accident. This can be disabled in the *Options* dropdown located in the header of the 3D View. Alternatively you can find the same option in the sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>) under the *Tool* tab in the *Options* panel as [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/78972/%E1%B4%8A%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%84%CA%9C%CA%8F%E1%B4%8D-%E1%B4%8D%C9%AA%E1%B4%84%CA%9C%E1%B4%80%CA%9F) noted.

[image: Header options]

[image: Sidebar options]

Comment: For those who don't have the *Toolbar* header enabled, it's in *Sidebar > Tool > Options*.

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved my problem!!!

Comment: thank you! really

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly... Is there a way for this to happen by accident? I didn't even have the tool pane open when this happened :/