# Why do the movement arrows move but the object doesn't move?

Tags: transforms

My first day with Blender and I can't move a cube in the way that youtube claims that I can. I want to be like youtube.
To walk you through what I do:

1. Open up Blender.
2. New File > General.
3. Right click cube (the cube has a red outline,not yellow)
4. Object Mode > Move.
5. Right click green y-axis arrow and move mouse on the y-axis.

The arrows move but the cube does not.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164936/can-only-move-object-origin-in-object-mode-cant-move-the-mesh

Comment: Why is the outline red? Do I need to select something from the "Transform Affect Only"?